# Fix the label width on text length increase

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a label, a textInput and a button. On button click text of textInput assign to text of label. Width of the label is 50.

But if the textInput length is greater than 8 then the label appears like below image

[image: My OutPut]

Objective:- I want my output as below image

[image: Expected OutPut]

And my code looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    width="400" height="200">

    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.greensock.TweenLite;
            import com.greensock.TweenMax;
            protected function btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                lbl.text = inputTxt.text;
                trace(lbl.text.length,lbl.width);
                if(lbl.text.length > 8)
                {
                                  //need some code here.....
                    }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:BorderContainer height="100%" width="100%" backgroundColor="green" />
    <s:HGroup gap="10">
        <s:TextInput id="inputTxt"/>
        <s:Button id="btn" click="btn_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:Label id="lbl" width="50" top="50"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: So basically you want to crop your text to 8 characters and then add ... to the end? I'm confused because in your example "Good Morning" is over 8 characters, so the expected result should be "Good..."

Comment: it should be Good Mor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `maxDisplayedLines` will help you: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/TextBase.html#maxDisplayedLines

It should automatically truncate the text for you (add ... at the end). Just set this to 1.

Comment: can you help me how can i move the text like marquee effect in HTML and it should displayed all the text but the label was fixed. only text should be moved. i used tweenLite but it move the label from 100 to 0

Comment: This is another question that you can post. Basically a tween should do the job, I don't understand what's the problem..

Comment: ya i know tween should do the job but it moves the label. But my requirement is to move the text to left inside the label

Comment: Label **is** text. Why would you ever want to do such a thing?

Comment: Because its my clients requirement. when the text length more than 8 text should be move left.

Comment: Well then move the label! I don't understand how you expect to move the text but not the label, what's your point?!

Comment: ok if instead of label there is a button and i want to do the same effect in button label.... is this possible??